# Render a `<select>` for a belongs_to through model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionview

I want to create a `<select>` input for a belongs_to through model.

A `post` has_many `tags`, through `post_tags`.

Here are the models to help you picture it:

```
posts
  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :post_tags

post_tags
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag

tags
  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :posts, through: :post_tags
```

In my new post form, I want a select dropdown that has every possible tag. So it should be Tag.all with an option for each tag. How can I render this?

Here is what I tried:

```
<%= collection_select("post", "tag_id", Tag.all, :id, :name) %>

Error: undefined method `tag_id' for #<Post:0x007ffd464a62d0>
```

Comment: please post your models

Comment: Please also post whole error with views

Comment: What are you looking for? That is the html that rendered the error, and that is the entire error. Do you know the standard syntax for collection_select given just these models?

Comment: syntax is not an issue here issue is tag_id in collection_select http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

Comment: something like `<%= f.collection_select "tag_ids", Tag.all, :id, :name %>`

Comment: If you are using mysql then u need to create a join table..!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not select for a belongs to assication because your `Post` model has no column `tag_id`, so it was error. You can use a simple `select_tag` to render this select:

```
<%= select_tag "post[tag_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(Tag.all, 'id', 'name') %>
```